# Trouble reading a nested structure

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to read a JSON file using Unity's JSON utility, and the file looks like this:

```
{ "entries": [{
    "2019": [{
        "january": [{
            "6": [{
                "name": "Litago",
                "ingredients": [{
                    "kaloriar": "20",
                    "salt": "10"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

I'm struggling a bit with how I should set up my nested classes. I'm currently doing this, but it's not working.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Entries
{
    public KeyValuePair<string, List<Year>> Year;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Year
{
    public KeyValuePair<string, List<Month>> Month;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Month
{
    public KeyValuePair<string, List<Day>> Day;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Day
{
    public KeyValuePair<string, List<Meal>> Meal;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Meal
{
    public string Name;
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ingredients;
}
```

I read the JSON like so:

```
Entries entries = JsonUtility.FromJson<Entries>(JSONString);
```

Ideally, I would like to do something like:

```
Debug.Log(entries["2019"]["January"]["6"]["name"]); // Should print "Litago"
```

but as my classes are most likely not setup correctly, I get type errors. Any ideas would be appreciated, and suggestions for other better plugins to read the JSON is welcome!

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting? Also what happens when you do dot notation? entries.2019.January.6.name

Comment: JsonUtility is mostly fine (tm) but if you want another plugin, Json Dot Net.

Comment: Don't know how to do this with `JsonUtility`, but with [tag:json.net] you can deserialize your JSON using lists of dictionaries and lists of `Meal` objects, e.g. `public class RootObject
 {
  public List<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, List<Meal>>>>>>> Entries { get; set; }
 }`.  See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ld5BaB.  Does that answer your question?  Honestly that JSON is rather awkward though, do you have any chance to simplify the format?

Comment: No matter which serializer you use, I'm sure you don't want `KeyValuePair<string, List<T>>`, you'll want a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Can you provide a json with multiple years or months or even days ?

Comment: AFAIK Unity's JsonUtility cannot handle nested types, Lists, Dictionarys, KeyValuePairs, etc directly. From the docs - `Passing other types directly to the API, for example primitive types or arrays, is not currently supported. For now you will need to wrap such types in a class or struct of some sort.`. Newtonsoft can handle JSON like this in a much more robust and intuitive way, I would recommend using that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, how to access the data, you can simply do the following to access what you need.

```
   JObject entries = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
   Console.WriteLine(entries["entries"][0]["2019"][0]["january"][0]["6"][0]["ingredients"][0]["kaloriar"].ToString());
```

**Output**

```
20
```

**Create Dictionary of Dictionary...**

You can create a recursive method to build out your `Dictionary<string, object>` items. Reason it has to be Dictionary of objects is because you have dynamic values each time you go in sub node.

```
    public static Dictionary<string, object> BuildDictionary(JObject input)
    {
        var properties = input.Properties();

        // Terminator
        if (properties.ToList().Where(x => x.Name.Equals("name")).Count() > 0)
        {
            Day thisDay = new Day()
            {
                name = input["name"].ToString(),
                ingredients = new Ingredients()
                {
                    kaloriar = input["ingredients"][0]["kaloriar"].ToString(),
                    salt = input["ingredients"][0]["salt"].ToString()
                }
            };
            return new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Meal", thisDay } };
        }

        // Recursive
        Dictionary<string, object> obj = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (JProperty property in properties) 
        {
            foreach (var element in input[property.Name])
                obj.Add(property.Name, BuildDictionary(element as JObject));

        }
        return obj;
    }
```

**Usage in Main**

```
   JObject entries = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
   Dictionary<string, object> dict = BuildDictionary(entries);
```

**Resulting Dictionary**

```
{
  "entries": {
    "2019": {
      "january": {
        "6": {
          "Meal": {
            "name": "Litago",
            "ingredients": {
              "kaloriar": "20",
              "salt": "10"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you can access the data you are looking for very similarly to what you wre looking for.

```
Console.WriteLine(JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict))["entries"]["2019"]["january"]["6"]["Meal"]["ingredients"]["kaloriar"].ToString());
```

**Output**

```
20
```

In essence what you are doing is taking the array of elements and converting only elements into dictionaries for accessing the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to reverting to [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library, you could leverage it's extensibility points to build something very similar to your desired construct:

1. Override `[]` operator on a `List<T>` so it allows for string input and make chaining look more natural.
2. Override `ExpandoObjectConverter` that comes with Json.Net so it injects your custom lists instead of default.

Overall the code might look something like this:

```cs
public class SearchableList<T> : List<T>
{
    public object this[string item]
    {
        get { 
            var listItem = this.Cast<IDictionary<string, object>>().First(l => l.ContainsKey(item)); // I am assuming that your top level array items will only have one matching key
            return listItem[item];
        }
    }
}
public class MyConverter : ExpandoObjectConverter
{
    static bool IsPrimitiveToken(JsonToken token)
    {
        if ((uint)(token - 7) <= 5u || (uint)(token - 16) <= 1u)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool MoveToContent(JsonReader reader)
    {
        JsonToken tokenType = reader.TokenType;
        while (tokenType == JsonToken.None || tokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
        {
            if (!reader.Read())
            {
                return false;
            }
            tokenType = reader.TokenType;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return ReadValue(reader);
    }

    private object ReadValue(JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (!MoveToContent(reader))
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected end when reading ExpandoObject.");
        }
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                return ReadObject(reader);
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                return ReadList(reader);
            default:
                if (IsPrimitiveToken(reader.TokenType))
                {
                    return reader.Value;
                }
                throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected token when converting ExpandoObject");
        }
    }

    private object ReadList(JsonReader reader)
    {
        IList<object> list = new SearchableList<object>(); // it is quite unfortunate to have to reimplement all class just because of this one line.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                    return list;
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    continue;
            }
            object item = ReadValue(reader);
            list.Add(item);
        }
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected end when reading ExpandoObject.");
    }

    private object ReadObject(JsonReader reader)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = new ExpandoObject();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    {
                        string key = reader.Value.ToString();
                        if (!reader.Read())
                        {
                            throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected end when reading ExpandoObject.");
                        }                       
                        object obj2 = dictionary[key] = ReadValue(reader);
                        break;
                    }
                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                    return dictionary;
            }
        }
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected end when reading ExpandoObject.");
    }
}
void Main()
{
    var myConverter = new MyConverter();
    dynamic entries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>("your json here", myConverter);
    Console.WriteLine(entries.entries["2019"]["january"]["6"]["name"]);
}
```

you will notice, `MyConverter` has a lot of seemingly unrelated code, which is a bit unfortunate consequence of how `ExpandoObjectConverter` has pretty limited extensibility out of the box. You could potentially do just with stock standard `ExpandoObjectConverter` but the object it produces gets a bit awkward to traverse given your source json format.

Hopefully this gives you an avenue to explore.